# Determining URL path for AJAX file loading in WordPress

Tags: jquery, ajax, wordpress

I use the following code in my WordPress homepage template, and it works fine.  However, when I try to use it in a page with a different path, it fails to find the file.

How do I dynamically establish my home path no matter what page I'm on? (I don't want to hardcode the full URL)

Works in `mywordpress.com/` but not in `mywordpress.com/page/` :

```
// Initiate asynchronous load of xml data:
jQuery.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: "wp-content/themes/mytheme/data.xml",
    dataType: "xml",
    success: parseDataXML
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe an absolute url?

```
// Initiate asynchronous load of xml data:
jQuery.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: "/wp-content/themes/mytheme/data.xml",
    dataType: "xml",
    success: parseDataXML
});
```

Comment: No- won't load on any page that way

Answer (score 0):

```
url: "/wp-content/themes/mytheme/data.xml",
```

the "/" do the trick

Comment: No- that breaks it on all pages

Comment: that will always point to: mywordpress.com/wp-content/themes/mytheme/data.xml. Why it havent worked? What is the url you see on the console?

Comment: OK I see- It drops it down to the root of the domain, which would work on most occasions, but my site is installed on a subpath: mydomain.com/mysite/wp-content/... is what i have, but this goes to mydomain.com/wp-content/...

Comment: Same logic applies, fix your path and start it with the /, like url: "/mysite/wp-content/themes/mytheme/data.xml",